# Draw a text with center alignment in swift not working as expected

Tags: ios, swift, text

I have a Text "SUGUS" which I want to draw at point 100,100 with Textalignment=center. So I expect to have the Character "G" at the point 100,100 , because I like to center it.

Does someone know what I am doing wrong regarding following code ?

```
                var s: NSString=NSString(string: "SUGUS");
                var iTextPositionX:Int = 100;
                var iTextPositionY:Int = 100;

                let fieldColor: UIColor = UIColor.darkGrayColor()
                let fieldFont = UIFont(name: "Helvetica Neue", size: 12)
                var paraStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()

                paraStyle.lineSpacing = 6.0
                paraStyle.alignment = NSTextAlignment.Center;// <---
                var skew = 0.1

                let attributes = [
                    NSForegroundColorAttributeName: fieldColor,
                    NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: paraStyle,
                    NSObliquenessAttributeName: skew,
                    //NSTextAlignment: textalign,
                    NSFontAttributeName: fieldFont!
                ]

                var Textpoint:CGPoint=CGPoint(x: iTextPositionX, y: iTextPositionY);
                s.drawAtPoint(Textpoint, withAttributes: attributes);
```

Comment: `drawAtPoint()` just starts drawing text at given point. For alignment to have any effect, you need to use `drawInRect()` method.

Comment: I also tried with drawInRect, but also did not succeeded. And how would I know the Size of the Rect. I t depends how long text is  ?

Comment: Well, if you provide more space than needed, text will be aligned to centre of the frame..

Comment: Thanks Jakub. It works, when I give big values. Thanks !